# Regex replace all function

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have following example string:
`$0$aaaaa$1$bbbbb$2$cccccc`
where between dollar markers there are some numbers. I would like to use Regex to replace each number by number + 1, so the output should be:
`$1$aaaaa$2$bbbbb$3$cccccc`

How can I do this using Regex in C#?
I know how to find all the numbers:

```
string s = "$0$aaaaa$1$bbbbb$2$cccccc";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\$(?<myNumber>.*?)\$");

MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(s);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["myNumber"]);
}

Console.WriteLine("\n\nFinal string = " + s);
Console.ReadKey();
```

By `regex.Replace(...)` I can replace them all by one value, but I have no idea how to replace each number individually with regex.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Best regards,
Marcin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var result = Regex
    .Replace(input, @"(?<=\$)\d+(?=\$)", m => (int.Parse(m.Value) + 1).ToString());
```

Comment: +1 impressive! For anyone interested, more on what the (?<=...) and (?=) optimization mean [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#grouping_constructs)